# In Google Tag Manager is there a way to track when a hidden div is made visible?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a page that has a survey on it.  After the user answers 5 questions, a results div is displayed.  The person in charge of the site would like to track how many users finish the survey.  My best guess on how to do is to track when the div is made visible.

Does anyone have an example of this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track, but please show us the code you've tried.

Comment: I'm trying to do this via Google Tag Manager and I was looking for an example that did this.  Unfortunately, I do not have any code to share.